# Nearest neighbour repartition of random uniform variables

Tags: probability

I take $N$ independant variables $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ with the uniform law on $[0,N]$.

Then I order the $X_i$ and take the new variables $E_i$ such that $E_1 \leqslant \ldots \leqslant E_N$. (The $E_i$ are just the ordered $X_i$).

I would like to compute for $x$ a positive real number $$\mathbb{E}(\#\{i\leqslant N / E_{i+1}-E_i \leqslant x \})$$

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: How are the new variables $E_i$ are defined ?

Comment: I didn't want to influence you with bad ideas. What I tried is to say that   $$E(\#\{i/ E_{i+1}-E_i\})=\sum_k P(\#\{i/ E_{i+1}-E_i \leqslant x\} \geqslant k)$$. I also computed the law of the $k$-th point but it didn't lead anywhere

Comment: OK. So you mean $\mathbb{E}(\#\{i\leqslant N \color{red} | E_{i+1}-E_i \leqslant x \})$ ? Note the red, vertical line. If it is correct, how would you interpret this expression ?

Comment: @calcullus yes it's correct,. You may use" /", "| "or ", " inside your sets. It's the number of variables whose nearest neighbor is at distance at most $x$.

Comment: I would interpret it almost in the same way-but including the expected value. We will see, if someone has an idea.